# Windows Identity Foundation ( WIF ) - Principal/Identity not coming back from service

Tags: c#, wif, servicestack

I have a ServiceStack service that uses WIF - internally everything works great - the ClaimsPrincipal & ClaimsIdentity objects get created, adding/reading claims from them is no problem at all.

However when i try to get this object from a client (tried ServiceStack client and c# WebRequest) it returns only a portion of the object - regardless if i have WIF installed on the client and attempt to cast.  If i call directly and get the json result, this is all that is returned:

```
{"Principal":{"__type":"Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal, Microsoft.IdentityModel","Identity":{"__type":"Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentity, Microsoft.IdentityModel","Name":"BoogeyFace","AuthenticationType":"","IsAuthenticated":true}}}
```

How do i get the full WIF ClaimsPrincipal across the service boundary?

thanks :-)

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass your claims principal across boundaries rather than issue and consume saml tokens or wif cookies? What's the actual scenario?

Comment: Good question - its an SOA app and other services want to get the ClaimsPrincipal to interrogate and get claims info - otherwise what really is the point of ClaimsPrincipal?  I mean i could have just created a custom object that implements IPrincipal and IIdentity as i have always done in the past .. maybe i am missing something?

Comment: I don't quite get it and still believe you should pass saml or reuse the cookie. If you just want to pass claims around, pass then as a string-string dict rather than the principal object.

Comment: yea, thats what i'll have to do.. i guess this statement from WIF only means delegation from the backend services:

Identity Delegation. WIF makes it easy to maintain the identities across the service boundaries so that developers can achieve an identity delegation scenario.

Comment: I know how wif works but have never heard of or done myself passing the claims principal object. It is not intended to cross boundaries.

Comment: I see - its a ServiceStack service used only internally, we are trying to stay with json to keep traffic light - so the saml xml wont work, i'll just create a seperate call to get the additional info the user is looking for... @Wiktor --- but doesn't the statement by Microsoft say it IS intended to cross service boundaries '...WIF makes it easy to maintain the identities across the service boundaries..' - or is that by use of tokens for verification?

Comment: Yes, there are saml tokens which cross boundaries. Sending claimsprincipal would be like sending the formsidentity instead of the forms cookie. I doubt you'd ever do that.

Answer (score 0):

To reuse issued token you have to configure your service to save bootstrap tokens.
This seams to be called [save bootstrap context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.securitytokenhandlerconfiguration.savebootstrapcontext.aspx) in .net 4.5.
This will give you access to your token in `IClaimsIdentity.BootstrapToken` property. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.claims.iclaimsidentity.bootstraptoken.aspx) for more details.

Having your original token on the service side allows You to communicate with another service just as if You were on a client.
For example You could use `CreateChannelWithIssuedToken` which is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee708780.aspx).